# Conversion of hh:mm:ss to mm:ss doesn't work within for-each element

Tags: datetime, xslt, datetime-format

I am attempting to transform an XML file to a format that a third party software can read. My issue is in terms of how time is formatted in each of the XML files. The output from the first is formatted as hh:mm:ss however the target software gets confused and reads this as mm:ss. So any event appears to be 60 times shorter than it really is! I have been advised by the developers that I need to convert hours and minutes to minutes.

Early on in the template, whilst converting summary data, I have used the following:

```
<xsl:attribute name="duration">
   <xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor(dive/summary/calculated/@duration div 60), '00')"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="format-number(dive/summary/calculated/@duration mod 60, ':00')"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Which neatly converted 1:02:50 into 62:50. So far, so good. When I use the same construct within a for-each element then things don't work so well. The relevant part of my template is as follows:

```
<xsl:for-each select="dive/data/row">
   <sample>

      <xsl:attribute name="duration">
         <xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor(@duration div 60), '00')"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@duration mod 60, ':00')"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:attribute name="depth"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@depth, '0.00')"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="temp"><xsl:value-of select="@temp"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="po2"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@po2-av, '0.00')"/></xsl:attribute>
   </sample>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The following shows an example of the relevant part of my XML output:

```
<sample duration="NaNNaN" depth="7.30" temp="18" po2="0.65"/>
<sample duration="NaNNaN" depth="7.50" temp="18" po2="0.56"/>
<sample duration="NaNNaN" depth="7.50" temp="18" po2="0.55"/>
```

I have also tried to use a variable to format the time-stamps but end up with compilation errors within the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:variable name="dur" select="@duration" />
   <xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($seconds div 60) mod 60, ':00')"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="format-number($seconds mod 60, ':00')"/>

<xsl:attribute name="time"><xsl:value-of select="@dur"/></xsl:attribute>
```

Firstly can anyone explain why the number-format works in the first instance but not within a for-each element. Secondly I would appreciate thoughts on what XLST code would work.

EDIT: sample input XML now included:

```
<dive UID="VMS-RED-5051_#-127#4AB4B4675CCE7036_dive_842960947_3084" profile="1" interface-version="vms-2-5" code-version="3.1.9" record-interval="5" serial-number="4AB4B4675CCE7036" records="755" total-hours=" 47" summary-only="false">
   <summary time-start=" 842960947" max-depth=" 30.84" time-end=" 842964718" time-offset="-127" time-datum="1991-12-31 00:00:00">
      <tissues ... </tissues>
      <gasses> ... </gasses>
      <calculated duration="3771" start-date="2018-09-16 11:51:14" average-depth="13.277" average-tpm="12.877"/>
   </summary>
   <data>
      <row index="0" depth="1.1" po2-av="0.64" valve="71" temp="19" filter="68" gas-no="1" bat-2="3.96" bat-1="3.96" hp-dil="219" hp-02="175" po2-cell-1="0.64" po2-cell-2="0.65" po2-cell-3="0.65" setpoint="0.60" tissue-ceiling="0" hud="1" sensor_flags="97" co2="0.00" duration="00:00:00">
         <tpm .../>
      </row>
      <row index="1" depth="1.1" po2-av="0.64" valve="0" temp="19" filter="68" gas-no="1" bat-2="3.96" bat-1="3.96" hp-dil="218" hp-02="175" po2-cell-1="0.64" po2-cell-2="0.65" po2-cell-3="0.65" setpoint="0.60" tissue-ceiling="0" hud="1" sensor_flags="97" co2="0.00" duration="00:00:05">
         <tpm .../>
      </row>
      ...
      <row index="752" depth="1.7" po2-av="0.89" valve="6" temp="14" filter="37" gas-no="1" bat-2="3.95" bat-1="3.95" hp-dil="168" hp-02="117" po2-cell-1="0.89" po2-cell-2="0.88" po2-cell-3="0.90" setpoint="0.92" tissue-ceiling="0" hud="1" sensor_flags="97" co2="1.25" duration="01:02:40">
         <tpm .../>
        <alarms>
           <alarm> ... </alarms>
      </row>
      <row index="753" depth="0.9" po2-av="0.87" valve="4" temp="14" filter="37" gas-no="1" bat-2="3.95" bat-1="3.95" hp-dil="168" hp-02="117" po2-cell-1="0.87" po2-cell-2="0.86" po2-cell-3="0.88" setpoint="0.86" tissue-ceiling="0" hud="1" sensor_flags="97" co2="1.27" duration="01:02:45">
        <tpm .../>
        <alarms>
           <alarm> ... </alarms>
      </row>
      <row index="754" depth="0.2" po2-av="0.77" valve="0" temp="14" filter="37" gas-no="1" bat-2="3.95" bat-1="3.95" hp-dil="168" hp-02="116" po2-cell-1="0.77" po2-cell-2="0.77" po2-cell-3="0.78" setpoint="0.80" tissue-ceiling="0" hud="1" sensor_flags="97" co2="1.27" duration="01:02:50">
        <tpm .../>
        <alarms>
           <alarm> ... </alarms>
      </row>
    </data>
</dive>
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your input XML (in particular for the path `dive/data/row`). Thank you

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for looking into this for me. A sample of the input is set out below:

Comment: I don't see any input.... ;) But, in anycase, it is best to edit your question, and show the input XML in there, as code is hard to read in comments. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Tim, input code is now at the bottom of the original question as an EDIT. KRs, Matt

Answer (score 0):

On your `calculated` element, the duration attribute has value "3771" which is a number (of seconds?)

However, on the `row` element, the duration attribute has value "01:02:40" (for example) which is not a number, and so you cannot perform numeric calculations on it.

However, you can use some string functions to extract the components, and perform numeric functions on that.

For example

```
<xsl:attribute name="duration">
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(substring-before(@duration, ':')) * 60 + number(substring-before(substring-after(@duration, ':'), ':')), '00')"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(@duration, ':'), ':')" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

However, if you can use XSLT 2.0, you can make use of `format-time` to make it a bit more readable

```
<xsl:attribute name="duration">
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(xs:integer(format-time(@duration, '[H1]')) * 60 + xs:integer(format-time(@duration, '[m1]')), '00')" />
  <xsl:value-of select="format-time(@duration, '[s01]')" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

(Where `xs:` is declared as namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`)

Comment: You are right - the duration attribute is in seconds. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are doing arithmetic on the @duration attribute:

```
floor(@duration div 60)
```

The `@duration` attribute in your example input is not a number:

```
duration="00:00:00"
```

Arithmetic on values that aren't numbers gives you `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Appreciated.